# Import Local Picture to XML for Cross-Platform App

Tags: javascript, xml, nativescript

I am currently working on a NativeScript App. I am having trouble using a locally saved picture on this app. I need to be able to maximize this said picture in XML and make it transparent so it allows movement to the next page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on how you are storing your image; if it is in the app folder then you need:

```
<Image src="/path/to/local/image">
```

If it is in the app_resources folder then you need

```
<Image src="res://image_name">
```

Add a width and a height to size it

```
<Image width="300" height="300">
```

Add some css for transparency:

```
Image {opacity: 50;}
```

If you are needing a button (for navigation) above it then you should do:

```
<GridLayout rows="auto">
   <Image row="0" ... other params .../>
   <Button row="0" ... other params .../>
</GridLayout>
```

Grid layout will allow you to stack items in the same display area.

Comment: Quick Question, I am trying to add both the picture and the button on the same page but the XML code seems a little off. I basically have the XML code so that the picture is stretched full screen and the button needs to appear on top. Any idea on how I can make this happen? I have been trying to use gridlayout but it doesnt seem to work properly. Thanks for your help!!

Comment: The sample code <GridLayout rows=1><Image><Button></GridLayout> above should work.  What issue are you seeing by using that code?

Comment: So I have something like this now:


    <GridLayout rows="1">
     <Image row="0"/>
     <Button row="1"/>
       <Image src = "~/images/001-startscreen.jpg" stretch="aspectFill"/> 
      <Button text="Next Screen" tap="tapAction"/> 
    </GridLayout>
But the image seems to be completely overlapping the image.

Comment: Please note currently the Later items overlap the earlier items.

Comment: Ok that makes sense, thanks! I fixed it by putting the button text on the bottom but the image that I am working with still seems too blown up and zoomed in, i was basically looking for the stock picture with the button on the bottom.

Comment: Well, you might need to set the Image size, by using stretch="aspectFill" the image will be sized up or down depending on the size of the image container.  If the image container is bigger than the actual image, then the image will look pixelated and blown up.

Comment: Yup I fixed it as I was toggling through it. Sorry for the myriad of questions, My next step is to make 3 different pictures on the next page so that each of those pictures, once you click on them will take you to a new page. Would I go about using gridlayout for that or something different. Essentially: 3 pictures in essentially a stack layout, but each picture would take you to its new page.

Comment: If the three images are on top of each other just use a StackLayout; always use the simplest view you can.  Your app will run faster...